# scaffold-DbContext , command results in exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core, ef-core-5.0

When attempted to run a scaffold command I am now receieving the exception noted below. It may be important to note that this stopped working all of a sudden.

Command executed

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=tcp:<CONNECTION STRING REMOVED FOR STACK OVERFLOW POST>;Initial Catalog=DATABASENAME;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=DBUSER;Password=PASSWORD;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir EntityModel -Force -Context "THECONTEXT"
```

Resulting Exception thrown:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
 ---> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.SemanticVersionComparer' from assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=5.0.16.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'
```

Installed EF CORE Packages
[image: installed packages ef core 5]

Comment: Check the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore package version, try to update/install/re-install the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 5.0 package.

Comment: @Zhi Lv, this is the correct answer. Please post as an answer so that I can mark as correct

Comment: glad to hear that it helps you solve the problem, I have added it as an answer, hope it can help others who meet the same error. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue relate the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore package version, try to update/install/re-install the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 5.0 package.